# Opening a Visual Studio 2017 .Net Core 2.1 Api in Rider

Tags: rider

I have been stuck on this for hours. I have an existing solution for a .Net Core 2.1 Api that was originally created in Visual Studio 2017. I am trying to switch to Rider, but when I open the solution, I cannot get it to run. Under Run/Debug Configuration, the Project option just says "No projects to run". I have tried forcing it via a .Net executable, I have tried changing the project GUID to FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC I just cannot get it to recognise and run this Api.

It run in IIS Express in Visual Studio 2017, if that helps.

Comment: Probably RIder thinks this is NOT a web application somewhy... Could you create a sample project with the issue for us and fire a ticket in our public issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RIDER or just leave it here =) I will check.

Answer (score 0):

In trying to anonymize the solution to send to Jetbrains I actually found the problem.

The problem was with out launchsettings.json, it specified a SSL port, and it seemed Rider did not like this. As soon as it was removed, and Rider restarted, the project loaded as expected.

```
  "WebApi": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44306/",
      "sslPort": 44360 <--- Remove this line
    },
```